# Неугомонное подключение к базе EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, asp

Удалил connectionString в web.config. В IIS в строках подключения все пусто. В коде нигде не было явно указано. Через SQL Express закрыл все подключения к базе. Но при запуске приложения оно все равно к ней подключается.  Вопрос, как оно это делает?

Comment: Это можете сказать только вы. Думаю, если в вашем приложении будет только `Console.WriteLine("hello world");`, подключения к базе данных не произойдёт.

Comment: @VlaD тогда как оно понимает, что нужно именно к этой базе подключиться? Где править, чтобы подключить к другой?

Comment: А что вы передаете в конструктор контекста? И что он передает в конструктор базового класса?..

Comment: [Тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/jj592674.aspx) подробно рассказывается как EF подключается к бд и самостоятельно создает строку подключения в зависимости от имени контекста.