# Asp.net строка подключения

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Как в *Code First* установить `ConectionString` (Строку подключения), если у меня стоит не *Express версия sql server*?

Answer (score 1):

web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх;Initial Catalog=DB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=usernamefordatabase;Password=password"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**UPD:** Вот [[тут]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445181/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-entityframework), кстати, ссылаются на вот [эту](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/jj592674.aspx) интересную статью по теме.